# Laravel 5.1 email views and templates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use sections and templates using Laravel 5.1, however when sending emails the HTML template does not get parsed.

For example the following code results in just the `content` part being sent and no HTML template (`emails.template`) with it;

```
@extends('emails.template')

@section('content')

    Hi there!<br><br>

    Please click on the link below to reset your password:<br><br> 

    {{ url('password/reset/'.$token) }}<br><br>

    <strong>Note:</strong> This is an automatically generated email, please do not reply.

@endsection
```

My `emails/template.blade.php` file looks like this:

```
@yield('header')
@yield('content')
@yield('footer')
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure emails.template exists and is in appropriate folder?

Comment: Check the file name template.blade.php

Comment: @trainoasis yes it does exist and is in the correct folder.

Comment: @Vinod VT there are no issues with the `template.blade.php` file, for some reason Laravel doesn't seem to be parsing it correctly.

Comment: What does your `resources/views/emails/template.blade.php` file look like?

Comment: @patricus I have posted it above in my original question.  The header / footer templates contain HTML.

Comment: Your view does not define any `header` or `footer` sections. Where are you expecting this data to come from?

Comment: @patricus I have tried changing my `template.blade.php` file to the following but no success: `@section('header')
 @include('emails.header')
@endsection

@yield('content')

@section('footer')
 @include('emails.footer')
@endsection`

Comment: You're close. I added an answer. When defining sections in the layout, you end them with `@show`, not `@endsection`.

Comment: Is the email view of the content (not the template) also saved with a ```.blade.php``` extension? ```.blade.php``` is required to get parsed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown, the issue is that your layout is expecting the view that extends it to define the 'header', 'content', and 'footer' sections. Since your view only defined the 'content' section, that is all that is going to be shown.

If you have `emails/header.blade.php` and `emails/footer.blade.php` partials you would like to show, this is not the correct syntax. To do that, you would need to `@include` these partials. You can include them inside sections, if you want the view to be able to overwrite them, though.

You're looking for something like the following:

```
@section('header')
    @include('emails.header')
@show
@yield('content')
@section('footer')
    @include('emails.footer')
@show
```

Now, your 'header' and 'footer' sections will default to what is included in your `emails/header.blade.php` and `emails/footer.blade.php` files, but they can still be overwritten (or appended to) in the actual view by defining it's own 'header' and 'footer' sections.